# how to create many subsets of existing paths?

Tags: julia, openstreetmap

In OpenStreetMapX we can create random path via:

```
using OpenStreetMapX

map_file_path = joinpath(dirname(pathof(OpenStreetMapX)),"..","test/data/reno_east3.osm")
mx = get_map_data(map_file_path, use_cache=false);
using Random 
Random.seed!(0)
node_ids = collect(keys(mx.nodes)) 
routes = Vector{Vector{Int}}()
visits = Dict{Int,Int}()
for i in 1:10
    a,b = [point_to_nodes(generate_point_in_bounds(mx), mx) for _ in 1:2]
    route, route_time = OpenStreetMapX.shortest_route(mx,a,b)
    if route_time < Inf # when we select points neaer edges no route might be found
        push!(routes, route)
        for n in route
            visits[n] = get(visits, n,0)+1
        end 
    end
end                                   
println("We have generated ",length(routes)," non-empty routes")
```

Now that we have 10 different paths, I wonder how can I randomly generate 100 subpath of the size p (where p be somewhere between 3rd to half of the actual path)? that is to have random 100 different path that are a subset of one of the above 10 paths?
Like if path 1 is ABCDEFGHIJ then a three subsets of it to be BCDE,  CDEF, DEFG

I don't know if there is any direct command within OpenStreetMapX, but I think because the output is `0-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}` there might be a way to do it with Julia list?

```
10-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
[
  [1793, 1038, 1286, 3086, 2631, 4205, 4205, 3086, 4205, 3086, 2468, 2985, 5674, 5674, 2985, 2985, 2985, 8894, 2985, 2985],
  [1031, 1031, 1031, 1031, 1031, 4402, 1031, 1031, 1032, 1032, 2987, 2987, 2987, 4205, 4250, 4250, 4246, 4247, 4247, 8318],
  [2465, 4242, 3874, 4872, 2465, 4207, 4243, 4243, 4242, 4243, 7495, 2774, 5676, 5871, 2774, 7319, 2774, 2774, 2774, 1006]
]
....
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you have something like this in mind?

```
# the lth element of out, starting at s, and having a length of p
l, s, p = rand(1:length(out)), rand(1:length(out[1])), rand(length(out[1])÷3:length(out[1])÷2) # 2, 2, 10
out[l][s:s+p-1]
```

Output:

```
10-element Vector{Int64}:
 1031
 1031
 1031
 1031
 4402
 1031
 1031
 1032
 1032
 2987
```

```
out = [
  [1793, 1038, 1286, 3086, 2631, 4205, 4205, 3086, 4205, 3086, 2468, 2985, 5674, 5674, 2985, 2985, 2985, 8894, 2985, 2985],
  [1031, 1031, 1031, 1031, 1031, 4402, 1031, 1031, 1032, 1032, 2987, 2987, 2987, 4205, 4250, 4250, 4246, 4247, 4247, 8318],
  [2465, 4242, 3874, 4872, 2465, 4207, 4243, 4243, 4242, 4243, 7495, 2774, 5676, 5871, 2774, 7319, 2774, 2774, 2774, 1006]
]
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark but no, this is not working, as in path orders matter and also  repetition does not make sense like the one happens for the second list in out

Comment: hi @Rainbow a couple of clarifying things: 1. the elements of `out` are paths, and the numbers are the letters, right? 2. The repetition in the numbers, you mean? They were there in the example input (?) you gave

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is good enough, although using an explicit `for` loop might be easier for code clarity.

```
julia> P = [
         [1793, 1038, 1286, 3086, 2631, 4205, 4205, 3086, 4205, 3086, 2468, 2985, 5674, 5674, 2985, 2985, 2985, 8894, 2985, 2985],
         [1031, 1031, 1031, 1031, 1031, 4402, 1031, 1031, 1032, 1032, 2987, 2987, 2987, 4205, 4250, 4250, 4246, 4247, 4247, 8318],
         [2465, 4242, 3874, 4872, 2465, 4207, 4243, 4243, 4242, 4243, 7495, 2774, 5676, 5871, 2774, 7319, 2774, 2774, 2774, 1006]
       ];

julia> num_subpaths = 5;

julia> [p[(K=length(p); L=rand(K÷3:K÷2); (1:L).+rand(0:K-L))] for p in rand(P, num_subpaths)]
5-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [3874, 4872, 2465, 4207, 4243, 4243, 4242, 4243, 7495, 2774]
 [2987, 2987, 2987, 4205, 4250, 4250, 4246, 4247]
 [1032, 1032, 2987, 2987, 2987, 4205, 4250, 4250, 4246, 4247]
 [1031, 1032, 1032, 2987, 2987, 2987, 4205]
 [3874, 4872, 2465, 4207, 4243, 4243, 4242, 4243, 7495, 2774]
```